# Capturing types from parameter pack and creating an array of unique_ptr from them

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, unique-ptr

I want to build a container class for my `Component` instances. Component is an abstract class and every type in the parameter pack should be derived from it.

```
 template<typename... TComponents>
class ComponentContainer {

    using ComponentPtr = unique_ptr<Component>;
public: 
    ComponentContainer() 
    {
         
    }

     
private:
    std::array<ComponentPtr, sizeof...(TComponents)> m_components;
};
```

The container should hold an array of pointers to the instances of each types provided.
So for every type there has to be `m_components[i] = std::make_unique<TComponents>`().

1. How can I write it in code?
2. Is there a way to validate that all the provided `TComponents` are derived from `Component` type?

Comment: `std::array<ComponentPtr, sizeof...(TComponents)> m_components{std::make_unique<TComponents>()...}`?

Comment: "_Is there a way to validate [...]_": `static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<Component, TComponents> && ...));`? (Although the array initialization will automatically fail if that isn't satisfied and `std::is_convertible_v<TComponents*, Component*>` might be a better choice, since you really want to test for _public_ inheritance.)

Comment: "*Component is an abstract class and every type in the parameter pack should be derived from it.*" Why are you taking a compile-time sequence of types that have a runtime polymorphic interface? Why not just take any `Component`-derived object as a list of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I write it in code?

You could add a constructor that moves or copies the components supplied to your array using `std::make_unique`:

```cpp
#include <utility> // std::forward

template <typename... TComponents>
class ComponentContainer {
    using ComponentPtr = std::unique_ptr<Component>;

public:
    ComponentContainer()  // default construct components
        : m_components{std::make_unique<
              std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<TComponents>>>()...} {}

    template <class... Args>
    ComponentContainer(Args&&... comp)  // move/copy construct components
        : m_components{std::make_unique<
              std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<TComponents>>>(
              std::forward<Args>(comp))...} {}
private:
    std::array<ComponentPtr, sizeof...(TComponents)> m_components;
};

// deduction guide
template <class... Args>
ComponentContainer(Args...) ->
    ComponentContainer<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PnqqKobh9)

Making `TComponents...` part of the type can be problematic though. If an element in the array was initialized as the derived type `C1`, it will be odd if you later make the `unique_ptr` point at a `C2`. The template parameters and the contained object types won't match anymore.

Also, if you specify the template parameters explicitly, you may make them `const`, but the container itself can't mix non-`const` and `const` `Component` pointers, so they'll have to be non-`const`.

For both those reasons, you should probably not let users get non-`const` access to the individual `unique_ptr`s directly.

You could add `tuple`-like `get` member functions to get a reference to the contained type with the correct `const` qualification:

```cpp
// helper trait to get the specific type out of a template parameter pack
template <size_t I, class... Args>
using type_in_pack_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Args...>>;

// ...

    template <std::size_t I>
    const auto& get() const {  // definite const&
        return *static_cast<type_in_pack_t<I, TComponents...>*>(
            m_components[I].get());
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    decltype(auto) get() {  // non-const& / const& depending on template params
        return *static_cast<type_in_pack_t<I, TComponents...>*>(
            m_components[I].get());
    }
```

It's often more useful to not make the concrete types of the components used to initialize the class template be a part of the final type. Since you store the elements in an `array`, the size of the array could be the template parameter instead:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
class ComponentContainer {
    using ComponentPtr = std::unique_ptr<Component>;

public:
    ComponentContainer() = default;

    template <class... Args>
    ComponentContainer(Args&&... comp)  // move/copy construct components
        : m_components{
              std::make_unique<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>>(
                  std::forward<Args>(comp))...} {}

private:
    std::array<ComponentPtr, N> m_components{};
};

// deduction guide
template <class... Args>
ComponentContainer(Args...) -> ComponentContainer<sizeof...(Args)>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c8n5Y7cK6)

> Is there a way to validate that all the provided `TComponents` are derived from Component type?

You'll get a compilation error if a pointer to one of the supplied `TComponents` (after `remove_const_t`) is not implicitly convertible to a `Component*`.

Comment: Thanks for help! I definitely have to get more experience with templates.